# Capturing packets using wireshark of an IoT device

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireshark

I have an IoT device that connects to my wifi router using wifi. There is a limitation of capturing network logs on the device itself so I thought to capture it using Wireshark.

I am using windows 10 and downloaded the latest version of Wireshark. Now that my laptop and my IoT device connect to the same network through the same router, I am not able to capture the packets in and out from my IoT device. I put the filer as ip.addr == {ip of the IoT device). But it shows nothing. Is it possible to capture these packets using a laptop using Wireshark?

Let me know, please.

Thanks

Akhilesh

Comment: The Wifi router has a built-in network switch that only sends data to those devices the data belongs to. To see the network traffic you need to redirect the traffic through your PC or alternatively use a network switch with dedicated TAP/MIRROR port, such ports can be configured to receive all network traffic that is received/sent from/to a different port (the one the IoT device is connected to).

Comment: ok. Thanks. Now I understand.

Comment: You can try using the internet connection sharing built into windows 10 (and xp,vista,7,8) to get the traffic coming through the pc itself.  That means your IoT device will use the wifi of the PC and the PC will be connected through ethernet.  Then you might have a shot.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I tried the same now and I can capture the packets now. Thanks . I thought there is a way to directly capture the network traffic.

Comment: There is.. sort of.. it's called promiscuous mode but won't give you what this will give you.  https://www.google.com/search?q=promiscuous+mode+wireshark